# Laravel 5 eager loading with variable model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to eager load a relation that is defined by a variable classname.  Here is what this looks like:

```
class Dashboard extends Model {
    public function modules(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Module');
    }
}

class Module extends Model {
    public function model(){
        return $this->hasOne($this->model_class);
    }
}
```

So the "model" attribute is a model of class `$this->model_class`

When I have a Module object and call

`$this->model`

I get the expected result.  But when I try to do

`$dashboard->modules()->with('model')->get()`

I get this error: `'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Class name must be a valid object or a string'`.  I assume this is happening because before the Module class is instantiated, there is no `model_class` attribute and therefore it cannot eager load the model.  How can I use eager loading in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: I think you should be looking at [polymorphic relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) for solving this.

Comment: I'm currently using polymorphic relationships but the issue with that is I end up calling many relations to get all of the modules for a dashboard.  ie. `$dashboard->modulesOfTypeA()` `$dashboard->modulesOfTypeB()` `$dashboard->modulesOfTypeC()` and then merge the results into a collection.  I would rather be able to call `$dashboard->modules()`

Comment: They may be polymorphic at the database level, but you're not using the Laravel implementation for handling them, otherwise you would be using `morphToMany` and `morphTo`, instead of `belongsToMany` and `hasOne`.

Comment: make a try with ->belongsTo()

Comment: @Bogdan I meant to say that I have been doing it with polymorphic relations, and this is my attempt at finding a better way.  If you look at http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations this example, that is how I am currently doing it.  However, in order to find all of the items associated with a tag, they call `$tag->videos()` and `$tag->posts()` just like I call `$dashboard->modulesOfTypeA()` and `$dashboard->modulesOfTypeB()`.  In that example, how could I call ALL of the related models from Tag, be they videos or posts?

Comment: Here are two other posts about what I am trying to do that appear to be unresolved: http://laravel.io/forum/02-11-2015-eloquent-polymorphic-many-to-many-morphto?page=1 https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2032 .  All of my different moduleOfTypeX classes adhere to an interface, so getting a collection of different classes would not be an issue.

Comment: Try to [lazy load](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading) your relation: `$dashboard->modules->load('model')`.